# Go Program Dockerfile Build Failed

Tags: docker, go, continuous-integration

The same `Dockerfile` successfully builded at local machine and one remote server. On another remote server in the office I have an error

```
emote: #9 [builder 5/5] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build   GOPROXY=direct go mod download &&   go generate ./... &&   go build -o sponsorship cmd/main.go
remote: #9 0.473 go: ariga.io/atlas@v0.9.1-0.20230119145809-92243f7c55cb: unrecognized import path "ariga.io/atlas": https fetch: Get "https://ariga.io/atlas?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup ariga.io on [fe80::1%wlp0s20f3]:53: dial udp [fe80::1%wlp0s20f3]:53: connect: invalid argument
remote: #9 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c GOPROXY=direct go mod download &&   go generate ./... &&   go build -o sponsorship cmd/main.go" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
remote: ------
remote:  > [builder 5/5] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build   GOPROXY=direct go mod download &&   go generate ./... &&   go build -o sponsorship cmd/main.go:
remote: #9 0.473 go: ariga.io/atlas@v0.9.1-0.20230119145809-92243f7c55cb: unrecognized import path "ariga.io/atlas": https fetch: Get "https://ariga.io/atlas?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup ariga.io on [fe80::1%wlp0s20f3]:53: dial udp [fe80::1%wlp0s20f3]:53: connect: invalid argument
remote: ------
remote: time="2023-03-06T17:14:09+03:00" level=warning msg="buildx: failed to read current commit information with git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree"
remote: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c GOPROXY=direct go mod download &&   go generate ./... &&   go build -o sponsorship cmd/main.go" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

env `GOPROXY=direct` does not change the result.

What can cause a problem? If to run docker build on server / laptop in the office, build is correct.

Docker make build transparent in theory, messy in practice.

Resolved by editing `/etc/networking` - adding nameservers. Thanks @erik258

Comment: `dial tcp: lookup ariga.io on [fe80::1%wlp0s20f3]:53: dial udp [fe80::1%wlp0s20f3]:53: connect: invalid argument`  that's not a valid IP address.  Your nameserver settings are not functional

Comment: Thanks for reply, @erik258. I should edit `/etc/hosts`, or it will not be enough? Maybe I should install some DNS server?

Comment: on a standard posix system nameservers are in /etc/resolv.conf. You can set it to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 if there's no reason to use a specific nameserver

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by editing /etc/networking - adding nameservers. Thanks @erik258

As I understand, `/etc/resolv.conf` sometimes (NetworkManager on desktop as an example) overwritten by network management software. In my case, I use mature debian `networking` service that has support of specifying DNS nameservers - it was my choice.

Please, correct or complement the answer.

Comment: Can you please put more details into your answer. erik258 mentioned adding name servers to /etc/resolv.conf, but you modified /etc/networking?